# Set Calendar to X Day in Month

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get a time down to the minute from a Calendar object built from four inputs: occurrence in month (3rd), day (Thursday), hour (1), minute(30), and am/pm. Also, if the time is in the past the month should increase by one.

How do I set a a Calendar to this time?

This code seems to not set the day.  The hour, minute, and am/pm are setting correctly though.

Calendar Setup:

```
long getTime() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH, getDayOfWeekInMonth());
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, getDayOfWeek());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, getHour());
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, getMinute());
    calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, getAmPm());

    if (System.currentTimeMillis() > calendar.getTimeInMillis()) {
        calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
    }

    return calendar.getTimeInMillis();

}

int getDayOfWeekInMonth() {
    return weekOfMonthSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition() + 1;
}

int getDayOfWeek() {
    switch(dayOfWeekSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition()) {
    case 0:
        return Calendar.SUNDAY;
    case 1:
        return Calendar.MONDAY;
    case 2:
        return Calendar.TUESDAY;
    case 3:
        return Calendar.WEDNESDAY;
    case 4:
        return Calendar.THURSDAY;
    case 5:
        return Calendar.FRIDAY;
    case 6:
        return Calendar.SATURDAY;
    default:
        return 0;
    }
}

int getHour() {
    return Integer.parseInt((String) hourSpinner.getSelectedItem());
}

int getMinute() {
    return Integer.parseInt((String) minuteSpinner.getSelectedItem());
}

int getAmPm() {
    switch(amPmSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition()) {
    case 0:
        return Calendar.AM;
    case 1:
        return Calendar.PM;
    default:
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Spinner Setup:

```
<string-array name="week_of_month">
    <item>1st</item>
    <item>2nd</item>
    <item>3rd</item>
    <item>4th</item>
 </string-array>
<string-array name="day_of_week">
    <item>Sunday</item>
    <item>Monday</item>
    <item>Tuesday</item>
    <item>Wednesday</item>
    <item>Thursday</item>
    <item>Friday</item>
    <item>Saturday</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="hour">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
    <item>4</item>
    <item>5</item>
    <item>6</item>
    <item>7</item>
    <item>8</item>
    <item>9</item>
    <item>10</item>
    <item>11</item>
    <item>12</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="minute">
    <item>00</item>
    <item>05</item>
    <item>10</item>
    <item>15</item>
    <item>20</item>
    <item>25</item>
    <item>30</item>
    <item>35</item>
    <item>40</item>
    <item>45</item>
    <item>50</item>
    <item>55</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="am_pm">
    <item>am</item>
    <item>pm</item>
</string-array>

adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.week_of_month, R.layout.spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
weekOfMonthSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.day_of_week, R.layout.spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
dayOfWeekSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.hour, R.layout.spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
hourSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.minute, R.layout.spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
minuteSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.am_pm, R.layout.spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
amPmSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use`calendar.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, <week of the month>);` and `calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 4);`.

Example -

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println("Before - "+calendar.getTime());
calendar.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, 3);
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 4);
System.out.println("After - "+calendar.getTime());
```

Result -

```
Before - Tue Feb 12 23:23:28 IST 2013
After - Wed Feb 13 23:18:16 IST 2013
```

Comment: I don't know the day of month. I only know nth day of the week in the the month and day of the week (i.e. The third Thursday of March);

Comment: shouldn't this be Thursday instead of Wed?